# I cannot add references in VS 2019

Tags: c#, reference, ide, visual-studio-2019

Fresh installed VS 2019
Opened a small project, that has no problems on the other computers here

But I get hundreds of errors :

> The type or namespace name 'system' could not be found.

My references look like this

[image]

When I remove a reference and add it back, it does not helps.
The properties stay empty.

I tried restoring nuget packages, as I find in many many questions here that this would solve it, but it does not help.
I tried starting VS as Administrator, it does not help
I tried clean/rebuild, restart VS, restart PC, all does not help

What to do ?

**EDIT 1**
I tried another small project and that has no problems.
So there must be something corrupt in some file of this project.
Anybody has any idea ?

**EDIT 2**
I noticed that when I get this project from TFS there is this message in the output window

> TF10121: The path '' is not found or not supported. Type or select a
> different path.

**EDIT 3**
I removed the project and got it again from TFS, now I also have this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on
> this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
> information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
> missing file is ......\Test
> app\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.2.1.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets. gttControls C:\Development\Palm\gttControls\gttControls\gttControls\gttControls.csproj  201

So I typed `NuGet Package Restore` but now I get this error

> NuGet : The term 'NuGet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included , verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

The NuGet Manager Gui does tells me I have this package already installed.

Now I am completely lost on what to do

Comment: Did you copy the error message verbatim? Because it should be `System` with a capital `S`. If you use a lowercase `s` you'll get the type or namespace error.

Comment: @JohnWu No I typed the message so it is actual with Capital S

Comment: Open "Visual Studio Installer" => Modify => Individual Components and ensure that you've installed the .NET Framework and targeting pack for the version that your project(s) use - check the .csproj file and look at value of "TargetFrameworkVersion". Other thing to check is NuGet package manager settings. For your NuGet packages,   check the following setting: In VS menu, Tools => Options => NuGet Package Manager => General => Default package management format

Comment: @user9938 I checked that all, these are all OK